# I can't search on ^

Tags: bug, search

I was trying to search for duplicates for this question:
[How to define the $0^0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259514/how-to-define-the-00)

But it's very hard to do this, as the search engine seem to ignore the ^ symbol.
Searching for "0^0" or "0 0" give exactly the same answers. 
There seem to exist a duplicate, but it's almost impossible to find with the search engine.

Comment: This is annoying, indeed. Ideally it would be nice to have the search engine go thru the TeX-sources. May be it cannot have access to those `for technical reasons'?

Comment: I can't even get Google to search for 0^0: "0^0" site:math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Graphth Your Google keywords turn up that question for me as a second result. It's definitely not great, though.

Comment: A very similar question: [Search queries involving symbols and/or $\TeX{}$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6180/search-queries-involving-symbols-and-or-tex).
Perhaps you will find something interesting in other question tagged [meta-tag:search], too.

Comment: Since Google cannot search for caret symbol, you could include some keywords to help you find what you need. Something like: [exponentiation "0^0" site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=exponentiation+%220^0%22+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Heads up, the [new search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) will allow this search (I've tested internally), quoted phrases exact matches should help on math quite a bit it seems.  We'll get the new engine rolled out to the network soon as we can.

Comment: @Nick: thanks! That change is very useful.

Answer (score 10):

This search is now allowed, for example you can search for ["0^0"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%220%5E0%22) or more relevant here since the start of it's latex: ["$0^0"][2].  We'll see how we can improve the "at the start/end of latex" since that `$` delimiter gets in there as part of the term.

It's better since you can at least find it at all, but searching latex we'll need to take a closer look at to see what can be improved - suggestions welcome here.

Comment: That is wonderful. May I post a small request about LaTeX? It might be wise to discard `{}` after all. Many people would write $\mathbb R$ and many others would write $\mathbb{R}$. The result is the same, and in fact is the same with $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb{R}$. Whereas the latter requires some sleek comparison of "equivalent" commands, the former merely requires ignoring {} or finding a nice way to allow stripping them and comparing to the term asked for.